# PS4 Remote Play on a Mac with a wireless controller

Tags: ps4, macos

I have paired my PS4 controller to my Mac using [these instructions](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/ps4-controller-mac/). It works wireless in for example KOTOR2 and recognizes it as PlayStation controller (given the fact that it uses PlayStation button icons in menus).

But the PS4 Remote Play app will not work unless I plug in the controller through a USB cable. It does say that you can use a USB wireless dongle, but that it not much better than a cable IMHO.

Any known tricks to get PS4 Remote Play app to work with the controller paired using Bluetooth, or will a different controller work at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In terms of "tricks" to connect via Bluetooth, the TekRevue article you used is *exactly* how it's done but an *important distinction that may have been overlooked is the article is descirbing how to connect the DS4 via bluetooth for general use rather than within the Remote Play App*. Note the results were tested by using a Sega Controller binding and using an emulator, **not** the Remote Play Application.

The PlayStation Remote app is proprietary as is the wireless dongle because it contains the key bindings and layout from the controller as designed to work with the first-party software.

It may be that the native support within OSX conflicts with the Remote Play App software or by design or two-party agreement given the ***very*** closed-system nature of both companies.

Thus, the simple answer is: *No.* It also means that a *non-DS4* controller *will not* (at this time) work with Remote Play